# Why do I get AttributeError: type object 'Placeholder' has no attribute 'loads', when running pyisntaller?

Tags: python, error-handling, pip, pyinstaller

I am using Python 3.10.6, pip 22.2.2  on Windows 11

I have a program which uses yfinance to grab stock data and sklearn.svr to predict stock data. I want to turn this program into a .exe file using pyisntaller. Pyinstaller finished and the .exe file is created but when I want to run it i get:

```
 File "PyInstaller\loader\pyimod02_importers.py", line 493, in exec_module
  File "requests_cache\__init__.py", line 7, in <module>
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1027, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1006, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 688, in _load_unlocked
  File "PyInstaller\loader\pyimod02_importers.py", line 493, in exec_module
  File "requests_cache\backends\__init__.py", line 7, in <module>
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1027, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1006, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 688, in _load_unlocked
  File "PyInstaller\loader\pyimod02_importers.py", line 493, in exec_module
  File "requests_cache\backends\base.py", line 18, in <module>
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1027, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1006, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 688, in _load_unlocked
  File "PyInstaller\loader\pyimod02_importers.py", line 493, in exec_module
  File "requests_cache\serializers\__init__.py", line 6, in <module>
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1027, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1006, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 688, in _load_unlocked
  File "PyInstaller\loader\pyimod02_importers.py", line 493, in exec_module
  File "requests_cache\serializers\preconf.py", line 122, in <module>
  File "requests_cache\serializers\pipeline.py", line 44, in __init__
  File "requests_cache\serializers\pipeline.py", line 44, in <listcomp>
AttributeError: type object 'Placeholder' has no attribute 'loads'
```

And when the pyisntaller is building the .exe file I get:

```
587 WARNING: Failed to collect submodules for 'pkg_resources._vendor.pyparsing.diagram' because importing 'pkg_resources._vendor.pyparsing.diagram' raised: AttributeError: module 'railroad' has no attribute 'DiagramItem'
```

So I think that the problem is because of matplotlib? I use it at the end to plot the predicted price.

The imports I am using on my program are:

```
import yfinance as yf
import requests_cache
import numpy as np
from sklearn.svm import SVR 
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import datetime as dt
```

**I ran the program by moving into the right directory and than running:**

> pyinstaller --onefile -w stockPredictor.py

Comment: please create an [example]

Comment: The first error seems to be related to requests-cache. I was getting the same error, tried disabling requests-cache in my app, and that error disappeared. Unfortunately, in my case, my app still isn't launching, but now I don't get any error messages.

Answer (score 1):

**Update:**

It looks like the root cause is that PyInstaller is not able to detect usage of the `cattr.preconf` subpackage from the `cattrs` library, regardless of any optional dependencies installed. Right now there are three possible workarounds:

- Use the latest requests-cache pre-release build (currently `1.0.0a2`)
- Add an explicit `import cattr.preconf.json` in your application
- Add `hiddenimports=['cattr.preconf.json']` in your PyInstaller spec

**Original Message:**

Looks like this is happening in [requests-cache](https://github.com/requests-cache/requests-cache), with a few different things going on:

1. There is a missing optional dependency, either for one of the alternative [cache backends](https://requests-cache.readthedocs.io/en/stable/user_guide/backends.html) or [serializers](https://requests-cache.readthedocs.io/en/stable/user_guide/serializers.html).
2. There is a bug causing an `AttributeError` to be raised instead of the correct `ImportError`.

   - Longer version: That `Placeholder` class mentioned in the error is used to wrap an `ImportError`, so it's only raised if a feature using that optional dependency is actually used (rather than raising it at import time). The fact that something is calling `.loads()` on that object probably means this is some weird corner case where the actual HTTP request succeeded, but serialization of the cached response failed. That might point to a missing dependency related to serialization.
3. That `WARNING: Failed to collect submodules` message seems to be unrelated.

Some things to try:

- Update requests-cache to the latest version (currently v0.9.6). That should at least result in the correct `ImportError` being shown.
- If you're using a different cache backend (other than the default SQLite), make sure any optional dependencies are installed for it. For testing, you can `pip install requests-cache[all]` to get all optional dependencies.
- If you're still getting that error, it could be that pyinstaller isn't correctly detecting usage of the optional dependency for whatever reason, and is omitting it by mistake. In that case, [pyinstaller's troubleshooting docs](https://pyinstaller.org/en/stable/when-things-go-wrong.html) are probably the best place to start. Adding a [hidden import](https://pyinstaller.org/en/stable/when-things-go-wrong.html#listing-hidden-imports), for example, may fix the problem.